# Changing background image of element in jQuery when page loads?

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm a bit stuck right now, I basically have my header element in the DOM and I have a background image hard coded in the CSS for the index page.

What I was looking to do was for this image to change on different pages. I thought this was going to be a pretty simple thing to do.

```
$('header').css("background-image","url(assets/img/consulting.png)")
```

I realise there is no event trigger, but I was under the impression that I wouldn't need to actually do that.

Also my CSS file and file for the page I'm adding the jQuery to are in different folders as is the img folder... I'm unsure where how I should be calling the url in the jQuery code. Should it be as though navigating from the CSS file or the HTML file?

Thanks guys, sorry if I missed something really obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the approach I would take, simply to remove the majority of the css from jQuery although you may simple want a click event.

I would do this for each page.

```
<body class="home">
<body class="about">
<body class="contact">
```

Then in your CSS do

```
.home header { background-image: url(../assets/img/consulting.png"; }
.about header { background-image: url(../assets/img/consulting2.png"; }
.contact header { background-image: url(../assets/img/consulting3.png"; }
```

If your site is a single index that loads content of the other pages without refreshing them you can do.

```
$(function(){
    $('#aboutlink').click(function(e){
        $('body').removeClass().addClass('about');

        //your other snippets here

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm going to go with this approach as it's probably better considering not everyone has JavaScript enabled. I still can't figure out why what I initially did didn't work though! Didn't even get thrown an error. jQuery mystery I guess!

Comment: Cheers. I'd say the majority of browsers have JS enabled these days but this is the better solution IMO because the CSS loads faster and is used in it's proper context. Using JS to do a job meant for stylesheets is a bit asinine to me.

Answer (score 0):

To change the initial state of the page, you have to wait to run your javascript until the page has been loaded.

There are several ways to do that.  The most common in jQuery are:

1) Use document.ready():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('header').css("background-image","url(assets/img/consulting.png)")
});
```

2) Place your code inside of `<script>` tags, but at the end of the body (right before the `</body>` tag) so it runs after the HTML has already been parsed.

You do, of course, have to make sure your image URL is correct too and has the appropriate path specification to be found by the browser.

If you control the HTML/CSS of the page, it is much better to just put the initial state into the CSS styles for the page as then the page will just be rendered the right way from the beginning rather than rendering one way, then use JS to change it to another way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've tried everything you've mentioned and I'm still not having any joy. I can't use the CSS to change the background-image because it would simply change the background-image on the other page. If I wanted to be a really lazy coder I could add a class for each individual pages header element and give each it's own background-image but I'd rather not! :P

Comment: @Dacu - If you can put javascript in one particular page, you can put CSS in that particular page too.  And the CSS gets parsed much earlier.  I'm not understanding why you can't use CSS or why the JS doesn't work.  Can you provide a link to the page?